# Anaconda Package issue: An internal module cannot find a data file located in the same directory

Tags: python, csv, package, conda, setup.py

I am building a python 3.6 package using the anaconda `conda` package framework.
The package seems to work fine with respect to the source files. There are no
build errors, etc. However, I am trying to add a new functionality where I store
some small CSV data files in the package. I want to load the data using `pandas`

The problem I am running into is that I cannot seem to reference the relative 
file path correctly from within the package. So code that would work if I were
in say a `Jupyter` notebook does not work when I am inside of a package. The 
path issue seems to be the way the problem presents itself, but I suspect it has
more to do with how the internal addressing is handled in a package.

The error message is:

```
 FileNotFoundError: File b'data.csv' does not exist
```

The strange thing about this error is that the `data.csv` file is in the same directory as the python file that is trying to access it. So I don't get why the python module `reader.py` below can't seem to find this file.

So let me give a minimal example of the package structure and code.

```
/project
   /docs
   /packaging
       /conda_build_files
           bld.bat
           build.sh
           meta.yaml
   /src
       /data
           __init__.py
           reader.py
           data.csv   #PROBLEM AREA     
       __init__.py
       module1.py
   setup.py
   README.rst
```

So the problem is that the file `reader.py` uses `pandas` to read the csv file
into a dataframe. `Module1` then calls on `reader` to obtain the data.

So the code is setup like:

```
##reader.py

import pandas as pd
class Reader():

    def read():
    return pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Then in module1 I have the code as:

```
##module1.py

from .data.reader import Reader
import pandas as pd

def main():
    dat = Reader.read()
    print(dat.head())
```

So this is where I am getting the odd error about `data.csv` does not exist. Now 
in this case I don't even need a relative import because the `Reader` class and
the `data.csv` file are in the same folder. Yes for some reason I get this 
strange error message.

The `data.csv` file is included in the `MANIFEST.in` file.

My `setup.py` looks like this.

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='pkg',
    version='0.6.0',
    description="desc",
    long_description=readme + '\n\n' + history,
    author="me",
    author_email='me',
    url='https://github.com/.../pkg',
    packages=[
        'pkg',
    ],
    package_dir={'pkg':
                 'pyugend'},
    package_data={
      'mydata': ['pkg/data/*.csv'],
   },
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=requirements,
    license="ISCL",
    zip_safe=False,
    keywords='pkg',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    ],
    test_suite='tests',
    tests_require=test_requirements
)
```

And the `meta.yaml` file is pretty vanilla too:

```
package:
  name: pkg
  version: "0.6"

source:
   git_url: https://github....

build:
  # noarch_python: True
  # preserve_egg_dir: True
  entry_points:


requirements:
  build:
    - python


  run:
    - python
    - numpy
    - pandas
    - docopt
    - matplotlib

about:

  license: MIT License
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite where `reader.py` exists, the instance of Python you create is running in the local directory you started if from.  In other words, if you open a CMD prompt (or terminal) in `C:\Users\krishnab` and start Python, that Python instance has `C:\Users\krishnab` as it's base location.

When `pd.read_csv('data.csv')` is called, Python looks for `data.csv` in the current working directory, which in this example is `C:\Users\krishnab`.

---

You can add an additional empty python file under /data.  It will only be used to get the directory of the `data.csv`.

```
/src
    /data
        __init__.py
        reader.py
        data.csv 
        other.py
```

and `other.py` has the contents:

```
# other.py
pass
```

In `reader.py` you can import `other` and use the `__file__` attribute to get the path.

The contents of `reader.py`:

```
from . import other
import pandas as pd
import os
data_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(other.__file__))

class Reader:
    def read(self):
        return pd.read_csv(data_dir+'/data.csv')
```

Comment: Okay, I get what you are saying about the working directory. But then how can I get it to reference the relative directory in which the data file is located? Like do I need to use the `os` package or something?

Comment: I have updated with additional information about how to get the path to the data file.

Comment: Ahh okay this worked. Thanks so much for your help @James. Interesting, I have not run into this problem before with relative paths, but now I can see the logic. It all works.